# Suppose $p(X \mid Y) = 1$, how do I show that $p(X \mid Y, Z) = 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, conditional-probability

Suppose $X, Y, Z$ are subsets of an event space and I know that $p(X \mid Y) = 1$, how do I show that $p(X \mid Y, Z) = 1$, in this case $Z$ can be any subset I guess. Here $p(X \mid Y, Z)$ refers to the probability that $X$ occur given both $Y$ and $Z$ occur. This statement makes sense intuitively, but how would I go about proving it from the basic probability rules, ie definition of conditional probability.

Comment: What you mean under $p(X \mid Y, Z)$?

Comment: Try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability) to rewrite $p(X|Y,Z)$ in terms of $p(X|Y)$.

Comment: what doe  $Y$ comma $Z$ mean?  That both $Y$ and $Z$ occur? That either $Y$ or $Z$ occurred. If it means $Y$ and $Z$ occurred then this is obvious.  If $Y$ and $Z$ occured then $Z$ occured and the probability that $X$ occurred given $Y$ occured is $1$>

Comment: @fleablood I get that, that's why I say it is intuitively obvious, but I would like to prove it rigorously from definitions.

Comment: If, accordingly your last edition, $Y,Z$  understand as $Y \cap Z$, then for any $p(Z)=0$ formula lost sense.

Comment: @zkutch Yeah, sure. We can make the assumption that $p(Z) \neq 0$, but I still would like a way to prove this statement rigorously.

Comment: So, you can show the converse of what you want: that $P(X|Y,Z) = 1$ implies $P(X|Y) =1$ because the event $X|Y,Z \subseteq X|Y$ and therefore,  $1=p(X|Y,Z)\leq p(X|Y)$ by monotonicity. But by the probability axioms, $P(X|Y)\leq1$, thus $P(X|Y)=1$. I don't see how to go the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, convince yourself that:
\begin{equation}
   Y\subseteq X \iff X\cap Y = Y
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
(hint: assume $Y\subseteq X$ and show inclusion both ways, i.e. that $X\cap Y \subseteq Y$ and $X\cap Y \supseteq Y$).

By assumption, and using the definition of conditional probability we have:
$$
P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X\cap Y)}{P(Y)} =1
$$
This implies that $P(X\cap Y) = P(Y)$. By equation 1, this is true iff $Y\subseteq X$.

By the definition of conditional probability (and assuming $P(Y \cap Z) \neq 0$):
$$
\begin{align}
P(X|Y \cap Z)&=\frac{P(X\cap Y \cap Z)}{P(Y \cap Z)} \\
&= \frac{P(Y \cap Z)}{P(Y \cap Z)} \\
&= 1
\end{align}
$$
where the second equality comes from substituting $X\cap Y = Y$ as justified in equation 1.

Comment: This looks good, but $p(X \cap Y) = p(Y)$ does not imply that $X \cap Y = Y$ even if $X \cap Y \subseteq Y$

Comment: @EdenHazard Yes, I agree (I also noticed this while writing). We need a more rigorous way to show: $P(X|Y)=1$ implies $Y\subseteq X$ so that we can apply Eqn 1. Any ideas?

Comment: No need to worry about this, I can prove it rigorously by first proving $p(X \mid Y) = 0 \implies p(X \mid Y, Z) = 0$ (which can be rigorously shown) and then using $p(X) = 1 - p(\bar X)$. Thank you for the help.